# Turn off abbreviations in Jupyter Notebook output?

Tags: python-3.x, output, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I am quite new to using Jupyter. I came across a rather annoying little thing in Jupyter: abbreviations. I have  a rather large - but not enormous - pandas dataframe. I would like to get some insights ont the missing structure. However, running `df_total.isnull().sum()` returns a list that is abbreviated with `...`(see below).

```
roe_before_tax_1               1101
roe_before_tax_2               1165
roce_before_tax_0              1009
roce_before_tax_1              1050
roce_before_tax_2              1115
                               ... 
revenue_by_fte_2                689
personell_cost_by_revenue_0    1144
personell_cost_by_revenue_1    1187
personell_cost_by_revenue_2    1271
```

Is there any way to get rid of that and to see the full output? Thanks! /R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pd.options.display.max_rows = 2000` (or `pd.set_option("max_rows",2000)` - use whichever you prefer!) Substitute 2000 for some number larger than the number of rows you want to display.

There's another option `max_columns` if you encounter the same problem with columns instead

Comment: in my case, another option `max_colwidth` is the right one  for display whole column data .

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanted to add extra space to the exhibition of columns. The command is:

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.set_option("max_colwidth", 40)
```

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately it is not possible with Jupyter at the time. Sorry!

Comment: Hi Brendan, thanks for the heads up! How do you know? Do they write something about it? Couldn't find anything on github thus far...

Comment: I spent hours trying to find the same thing out and contacted my genuis friend who told me. I  could be wrong though.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - it's just `pandas`'s default display options that need to be modified. Nothing to do with the notebook itself